# Prevent injected page from changing style in parent page

Tags: css, ajax

I have a very simple test page layout:

```
<div id="nav">Some content here</div>

<div id='siteloader'></div>
```

With some AJAX I load the content of http://www.example.com/ (literally this page)
 in **#siteloader**.
I load this page with a PHP script on my server, so no problems with Same Origin Policy

http://www.example.com/ has some styling like below

```
div {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 5em auto;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 1em;
 }
```

Now when I load the contents of http://www.example.com/  in #siteloader,  the above style also gets applied to **#nav**.

How can I prevent the injected page from overwriting the style of my document?  The style of the loaded document only needs to be applied to the contents of #siteloader

Comment: Load it inside an `<ifame>` ?

Comment: Or since you are loading via AJAX, modify the class/style on the fly?

Comment: Can't use an `<iframe>` because i need to access the page's code via jQuery.
Modifying on the fly is very hard to do, because the loaded page is not always the same. Could by every page on the web.

Comment: Is the www.example.com style embbed or inline?

Comment: @AndrewB Not sure what the difference is. You can check it out because i litteraly mean http://www.example.com/

Comment: That is embedded, which means it is in a "style" tag at the top of the page, compared to being an attribute in a tag e.g. "<p style='font-size: 2em;'">sometext</p>

Comment: You have control over both pages right. Why not just make sure you are naming your CSS rules in a sane manner to prevent this from happening? In other words use linked stylesheets in preference to `<style>` elements or in-line styling, make sure you have the proper CSS inheritance model in place, etc.

Comment: It is possible he cannot always predict what form the css will come in. Also he should not have to change his ways to suit the content which will not always be the same.

Comment: @MikeBrant,  I cannot change the naming of the CSS rules because I don't know what's being loaded. Can be al sorts of pages. 
Also,  I have a div `#nav` in my own content, but the style of that is being overwriten by the `div { } ` declaration in the page that I inject.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this within siteloader after where you get all the data in from example.com:

```
$("#siteloader style").remove();
```

Also just for your own benefit, there is an html5 tag called nav which is the same as div id="nav" except it is beneficial to web crawlers when they are indexing your page.

EDIT: I editted it to have "#siteloader style", this means only a style tag within siteloader is removed.

~Andrew

Comment: `$("#siteloader style").remove();`  means remove all the style from `#siteloader` ? 
That's not what I want, I need the style loaded from remote to keep the same, but I don't want it to interfere with the content already on my page

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood. I don't believe that is possible as you would have to identify what is useful and not useful on the fly.

Also if the style taken from example.com is something like "div{...}" that would naturally affect the rest of your page and you cannot change that.

Comment: Unless you used some script that would insert "#siteloader " (notice the space) in front of every css instruction, that would mean that only the content within siteloader could be changed to what was taken in from example.com

Answer (score 0):

Unless/until there's widespread browser support for [scoped styles](http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/), there are no simple solutions to your problem. If you're willing to rely on JavaScript libraries, there are a [couple](https://github.com/PM5544/scoped-polyfill) of [plugins](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin) that emulate scoped styles.

Comment: [This pluging](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin) seems to do what i want, but i cannot wrap my head around it. I guess all the styles in the injected page have to be scoped ? 
As i said before,  the injected page can by any page on the internet, so they can have inline css ( no need to worry about i guess), external stylesheets and embedded styles. How to handle this?

Comment: Added the `scoped=true` atrribute to the `<style>` element of the downloaded page by means of  preg_replace in the PHP script. And added `<script src="js/jquery.scoped.js"></script>` to my HTML file.
Didn't help.

Comment: Oh, forgot to add `onload="$.scoped(); `  to the body. Added it but nothing changes.Now also added a button with `onclick="$.scoped();`. Now when i load the page, the style of # siteloader messes up the style of the rest of the page as before.  But when I click this button, #siteloader is empty again and the rest of the page is'nt messed up anymore.  Strange.....